# zooming in in Octave GUI

Tags: octave

I'm using the Octave GUI, and I'm trying to Zoom in using shortcuts. `CNTRL + -` works for zooming out, but for some reason `CNTRL + +` does not work for zooming in, even though in the dropdown menu under "View", next to "Zoom in" it says ```CNTRL + +`` for the shortcut

Comment: are you pressing shift?

Comment: No I wasn't thank you that did it